# What is the tense used here?

Tags: tense, past-tense, past-perfect

I thought you would have eaten by now. 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . (OR) 
I thought you would have ate by now.

Which is correct?

What is the tense used here?

Answer (score 1):

"I thought you would have eaten by now" is correct. You have to use the past participle form of the verb with have/had to form the perfect tense.  "Eaten" is the past participle, "ate" is the past tense form.